# MySQL: Num Rows not working

Tags: php, mysql

I've stumbled upon a simple MySQL error, and it seems my attempts of fixing it are effortless. The problem, it's not counting.

Before I go further, I know that `mysql_*` is **Deprecated**, and that I shouldn't use it. I should use `mysqli_*` or PDO.

This is my Query, and yes, the `echo` is just for testing.

```
$ms_sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mijnsp WHERE sp_username = '".$user['username']."'");
    while ($mijnspusers = mysql_fetch_assoc($ms_sql)) {

    $ms_count = mysql_num_rows($ms_sql);

    if($ms_count <= 0){
        echo "Result is empty";
    }else{
        echo $mijnspusers['new_username'];
    }
```

I've tried to change the IF, but with no effect;

```
if($ms_count <= "0"){
```

or, like this

```
if($ms_count <= '0'){
```

Thank you in advance,
Pascal

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: You're just assuming your query is working, add error checking or look in your error logs.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard Like I said, I know that. However, the system itself is not mine, and that's a long time of converting everything. Thanks for the Filtering tips, but this is for now only on my personal computer. The Query itself works, when there is a Result, it shows it.

Comment: You need to cleanse your query before using it. Otherwise, what you have is a big SQL Inject Opening.

Comment: I hate when people say *"I'm not that far along..."* or *"This site will not be public..."* or *"It's only for school, so security doesn't matter..."*. If teachers and professors are not talking about security from day one, they're doing it wrong. They're teaching sloppy and dangerous coding practices which students will have to unlearn later. I also hate it when folks say, *"I'll add security later..."*. If you don't have time to do it right the first time, when will you find the time to add it later? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Use $ms_count = mysql_num_rows($ms_sql); outside the loop... In second iteration it will nothing return becuase u can't get mysql resource in second iteration

Comment: It's not just that it's deprecated, it doesn't even work in a current version of PHP!

Comment: what output are you getting? what output are you expecting?  Also, you should declare $ms_count outside the while loop to improve speed.

Comment: @miken32 This server doesn't run PHP 7. It's an old version.

Comment: @jay-blanchard one more thing sir... Students using deprecated things from day one y not new things

Comment: No doubt @devpro and we should enable students to have their teachers come up to date.

Comment: Off course I m very scare if teachers out dated .. Or maybe students using short cuts @jay-blanchard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call

```
$ms_count = mysql_num_rows($ms_sql);
```

before the `while()` loop.

Comment: Thanks. Stupid of me. I Do know this, just it's getting forgotten by time. Bad memory. This fixed it, ofcourse.

Comment: @PascalBoschma nice!

Comment: Most important is that if OP use inside the loop it will return nothing in second iteration

Answer (score 2):

You should do the `mysql_num_rows()` before going into the loop. If the num is 0, then you'll never run the loop to begin with.

Your code should be:

```
$ms_sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mijnsp WHERE sp_username = '".$user['username']."'");

$ms_count = mysql_num_rows($ms_sql);

    if($ms_count == 0){
        echo "Result is empty";
    }else{
        while ($mijnspusers = mysql_fetch_assoc($ms_sql)) {
           echo $mijnspusers['new_username'];
        }
    }`
```